# Solve an equaltion similar to Sylvester equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Suppose $A,B\in C^{N\times N}$ with their eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N$ and $\mu_1,...,\mu_N$ respectively.

Please give the sufficient and necessary conditions of that: there exists non-zero $X$ for this equation:

$A^2X+XB^2-2AXB=O$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: rewrite the equation as
$$
A(\underbrace{AX-XB}_{Y})-(\underbrace{AX-XB}_{Y})B=0.
$$
Can it happen that it has only the trivial solution $Y=0$?

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it... But how about the iff conditions?

Comment: @AndyWang The original equation has a non-trivial solution $X$ iff $AY-YB=0$ has a non-trivial solution. It is Sylvester equation with the known iff-condition in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (it is a linear homogeneous equation on $Y$).